# Convert Text String to HTML String

Tags: html, json, parsing, excel, vba

Is there a way to convert below text string to html string without using replace ?

**Text String**

```
 {"a":"\u003cul class=\"ylist ylist-bordered search-results\"\u003e\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cli class=\"add-search-result\"\u003e\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"search-result yla biz-listing-large www-yla-unit-color-555555-ffefcb\" data-key=\"ad_business\"\u003e\n\t\t\t\u003cspan class=\"yla-tip\"\u003eYelp Ad\u003c/span\u003e\n\n\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"media-block media-block-large clearfix main-attributes\"\u003e\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv"}
```

**HTML String**

```
{"a": "<ul class=\"ylist ylist-bordered search-results\">\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class=\"add-search-result\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"search-result yla biz-listing-large www-yla-unit-color-555555-ffefcb\" data-key=\"ad_business\">\n\t\t\t<span class=\"yla-tip\">Yelp Ad</span>\n\n\n\t\t<div class=\"media-block media-block-large clearfix main-attributes\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"media-avatar\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\t<div class=\"photo-box biz-photo-box pb-90s\">\n\t\t\t<a href=\"/adredir?position=0&amp;redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fbiz%2Fez-pawn-corp-new-york-3&"}
```

I tried below code but its not working as expected (excel-vba)

```
 Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerText = strDiv
    Debug.Print   html.body.innerHTML
```

If i copy the text string to `http://jsonlint.com/` to validate the string it returns the converted html string.

Comment: not trying to sound coy...but if ms dont provide a method, then you'll have to roll your own

Comment: + 1 I don't see a reason why this post was downvoted....

Comment: Why not automate it? Send the string to the that page and retrieve the results?

Comment: @SiddharthRout sounds like an overkill :P and what is he going to do if the website vanishes?

Comment: @mehow: Since there is no inbuilt method, this is the only option. And if that link dies, he can move on to next ;)

Comment: that's true @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. I have not added any error handling techniques. I am sure you can take care of that.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sURL As String: sURL = "http://jsonlint.com/"

    Dim StringtoConvert As String
    StringtoConvert = "{""a"":""\u003cul class=\""ylist ylist-bordered search-results\""\u003e\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cli class=\""add-search-result\""\u003e\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\""search-result yla biz-listing-large www-yla-unit-color-555555-ffefcb\"" data-key=\""ad_business\""\u003e\n\t\t\t\u003cspan class=\""yla-tip\""\u003eYelp Ad\u003c/span\u003e\n\n\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\""media-block media-block-large clearfix main-attributes\""\u003e\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv""}"

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate sURL

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait (1): Loop

    ie.document.getElementById("json_input").Value = StringtoConvert
    ie.document.getElementById("validate").Click

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: Wait (1): Loop

    Debug.Print ie.document.getElementById("json_input").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]